# Spliting multivalues in one single column based on two characters

Tags: sql

I am looking to break up multiple values in multivalues in one column and can be dynamic amount.   First character will be a number then : (Ex: 1: 2: etc.)  Then ending value will end with a

See example:

```
0:Certificate CN=*.eas.xmcxxxare.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days.101  Days Left  <br>, 1:Certificate CN=*.rss.wxxxxare.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days.   <br> 71  Days Left  <br>, 2:Certificate CN=*.hds.xxxgware.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days.   <br> 85  Days Left  <br>, 3:Certificate CN=*.cas.xxxxare.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days.   <br> 75  Days Left  <br>, 4:Certificate CN=*.isxxxx.mcgware.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days.   <br> 85  Days Left  <br>
```

```
New Column Name: Message0  
Value in Column: "Certificate CN=*.eas.xmcxxxare.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days."
New column Name: Message01
Value in Column: "101  Days Left"
New Column Name: Message1  
Value in Column: "Certificate CN=*.rss.wxxxxare.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days.."
New column Name: Message10
Value in Column: "71  Days Left"
New Column Name: Message2  
Value in Column: "Certificate CN=*.eas.xmcxxxare.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days."
New column Name: Message20
Value in Column: "85  Days Left"
New Column Name: Message3  
Value in Column: "Certificate CN=*.eas.xmcxxxare.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days."
New column Name: Message30
Value in Column: "85  Days Left"
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: 0:Certificate CN=*.eas.xmcxxxare.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days.   <br> 101  Days Left  <br>, 1:Certificate CN=*.rss.wxxxxare.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days.   <br> 71  Days Left  <br>, 2:Certificate CN=*.hds.xxxgware.com, OU=Domain Control Validated Will Expire within next 120 days.   <br>